# Adding create, edit, delete link of referenced entity in same content type

Tags: 8, entities

How could we interconnect referenced entity in one content type so that we can search, create, edit, delete the referenced entity on the same content page. 
In drupal 7 "references_dialog" module was fulfilling the requirement but now in drupal 8 what is alternative of that module.I think references_dialog is now no more maintained by developer for Drupal 8. I already know that inline_entity_form is there but i want some module which open every thing in modal window pope up like reference dialog does.

Any module or code suggestion will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a combination of inline_entity_form and [Entity browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser).

It's possible to create different browsers that consist of one or multiple views, dropzonejs upload forms (with the dropzonejs module), you could also integrate it with a create form I guess but there's no integration for that yet I think (within the entity browser, which is why you can use Inline Entity Form for that part directly in the widget9.

Entity browser doesn't have a UI yet to create browsers, but you can look at the provided demo module and adjust it to your neeeds.

Another example is the [File Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser) project. That uses an inline iframe, and not a dialog. And it's specifically for managing files/images.

Comment: Entity browser is a great solution but it is lacking in good documentation. I have tried it and it was working fine. But still need to know some more stuff like how to add the another entity browser view in form field for-matter, or how to make a valid YML file to import configuration. If you have any experience in it then please share it to community. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen https://drupal-media.gitbooks.io/drupal8-guide/content/modules/entity_browser/intro.html? (linked from the project page). Also follow https://github.com/drupal-media/entity_browser/pull/137, that should make creating custom browsers a lot easier.